# StorageFile contain data or not (windwos phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight

How to get StorageFile file contain data ? if not then

```
AreaTextBlock.Text = "1.8;"
```

my current code is:

```
private async void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
      StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("text.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
      await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "1.9");
}

private async void SettingsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("text.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
      AreaTextBlock.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

}
```

on button tap AreaTextBlock.Text is 1.9 but i need when button is never tapped then AreaTextBlock.Text should be 1.8

i didn't want to write AreaTextBlock.Text = "1.8" in xaml or in c# initialize because when exit and relaunch AreaTextBlock.Text is 1.8 even if its text is 1.9.
so how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need is to check at the end of the `Loaded` method if the `AreaTextBox.Text` is empty and if yes, set the default value.

```
if ( AreaTextBox.Text == "" ) 
{
      AreaTextBox.Text = "1.8";
}
```

Comment: ha ha i use this code before  AreaTextBlock.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

this is the reason why it wasn't work now its work thanks..